# Dropdown Menu in fixed header issues

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, scroll

I am building a [CSS3 dropdown menu](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) from Tutsplus (awesome site). I implemented the menu without any problems and it is working the way it should. My problem however, is that I am using this menu in a fixed header. I have a lot of content in this dropdown menu, and on a normal sized screen, I have no problem using `overflow-y: auto;` however, when the screen is resized, even with the scrolling, most of the menu is cut off. When trying to scroll with a mouse, only the content in the body of the page will scroll (due to fixed header). Is there a way that I can allow for only the div within the dropdown menu to scroll while the dropdown is activated (I am using a hover effect, but will use onClick id that is more feasible)? For example, something like Facebook, when clicking a menu item in the fixed header, only overflow inside the dropdown div will scroll. Thanks!

Comment: plz provide us with some code or jsfiddle...

Comment: Here is some code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micawley/LZjjT/) With the fixed object, I am trying to make the dropdown scrollable when it is active *updated

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar issue, but mine is for mobile and driven off a click event. My temp solution is to toggle the header from being fixed and follow the link to href="#top", but I'm a little concerned about the jumpyness.